# fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c++17

Using, CentOs 7.1, gcc version 6.1.0 (GCC) 
I receive this error:

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
```

on this line

```
#include <filesystem>
```

compiling with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++17
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Your configuration does not have the `filesystem` header. Was that not clear from the error? What is your question?

Comment: Does it exist on CentOS in the first place? filesystem seems to be a Microsoft thing

Comment: You might need to use the `experimental` namespace and directory (e.g. `<experimental/filesystem>`).

Comment: `<filesystem>` doesn't appear to be supported by gcc [yet](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z), but `<experimental/filesystem>` might be. Also try `<boost/filesystem.hpp>`.

Comment: <filesystem> is now fully supported by C++17, so you can now compile the original like so: g++-8 -std=c++17 demo.cpp. I agree that this question was fine. I had the same problem and ended up here.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It seems you have to include `<filesystem>` like this:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```

Don't forget to add `-lstdc++fs` as a GCC flag!

Here is the proof:
[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27d982408933ec9f)

If that doesn't work, then that probably means that you don't have `filesystem` in your configuration.

Also, as @MartinR. pointed out, the **`experimental` is no longer needed in GCC 8+**.

Comment: It works, thanks!

For a complete information:  
[link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r1.html)

Comment: necessary also using -lstdc++fs on gcc command

Comment: And you can use it in your code like this e.g.: namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

Comment: You can drop "experimental" if your gcc version is >=8.

Comment: I'm using g++8 and included `LIBS += -lstdc++fs`, and yet it says undefined reference. The experimental/filesystem works well. Does anyone have idea why experimental works but regular filesystem not?

Comment: @kocica I'm not sure I can reproduce, it might be some sort of mismatch on your machine. E.g it works fine on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j717aT). Did you include the `-std=c++17` flag?

Comment: Thanks for reply @ArnavBorborah. Yes I included this flag into compilation. And yes, it seems to be some kind of mismatch. Probably I will stick with `experimental/filesystem` :/