# Filesystem not found

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

Any time I try to use the filesystem library, it gives me  `error: 'filesystem' is not a namespace-name`
My Code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

I am using gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0.
Is C++ 17 not supported.

**EDIT:**

I found out that VS 2019 has a setting that allows you to change your C++ Language Standard.

Comment: what are the command line arguments?

Comment: Compilers normally don't default to the latest c++ version, so you most certainly didn't set any c++ version in your build command, or one that is older then c++17.

Comment: If your talking about when I compile it 
I do gcc filesystemtest.cpp 
if that is not what your talking about then I am sorry I am still learning C++
I normal compile using vs 2019

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231363/fatal-error-filesystem-no-such-file-or-directory/39231488). I might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I found it out turns out my c++ language standard in VS was c++ 14

Comment: You use GCC 9.2 and fixed the problem by changing a Visual Studio compiler setting? Weird.

Comment: You aren't compiling properly. Use `g++ -std=c++17 filesystemtest.cpp`

Comment: @HamedNorouzi, that's a rather outdated link. Using C++17, as the tags and post suggests, all that's needed is setting the compiler flag. Not using an outdated header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
```

Comment: I have tried that also but it says experimental not found Nevermind It works thanks

Comment: This is how I got filesystem to work using gcc with C++17 setting on an updated Ubuntu 18.04LTS using VSCode as the IDE. Thanks.